# Why enter/return/nextline key doesn't work when input type is set to Number Mode?

Tags: android

I have this code for toggleing input mode from text to number mode

```
public void inputMode(View v){
        Button b = (Button) v;
        if(b.getText().equals("123")){
            b.setText("abc");
            etdetail.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            etdetail.setSingleLine(false);
            etdetail.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.PARCELABLE_WRITE_RETURN_VALUE); //no effect
            etdetail.requestFocus();
            etdetail.setSelection(etdetail.getText().length());
        }else{
            b.setText("123");
            etdetail.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            etdetail.setSingleLine(false);
            etdetail.requestFocus();
            etdetail.setSelection(etdetail.getText().length());
        }
    }
```

Can any one tell me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
etdetail.setText(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```